# Saving and Reading Binary Image

Tags: python, opencv

Hello I want to save image after threshold:

```
binary=cv2.threshold(fark, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
binary.astype(np.uint8)
print binary.shape
cv2.imwrite("path"+str(counter)+".png",binary)
```

binary.shape output is: (320,240) ---> This is what I want

But when i read the image:

```
image=cv2.imread(path)
print image.shape
```

output is (320,240,3) , and when i check out the array it has values like 254,253

What can i do for this stuation and what is the best file format to save binary image?

Comment: First `binary.astype(np.uint8)` is of no use. To load as the original, the key is at `cv2.imread` .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `threshed` is already `np.uint8`, no change is needed.

```
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(fark, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
print(threshed.dtype, threshed.shape)
```

But when use `cv2.imread`, default convert to `BGR` channels. To keep original shape and channels(for `grayscale` or `png with alpha channel`):

```
img = cv2.imread("test.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Or just for gray:

```
img = cv2.imread("test.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it still has values like 254,253(not a big problem). What file format is good for binary image?

Comment: It's not need to save as bit? Defaultly image data is np.uint8. You can transform the data to in your code after loaded . And Why exist 254, 253? All data should be `0` or `255` if thresholded.

Comment: I think imwrite and saving as an image makes it 254 thanks for advice